# Type annotations can only be used in TypeScript files.ts(8010)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm getting error on `React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>`

```
const handleOpenNavMenu = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => {
    setAnchorElNav(event.currentTarget);
};
```

```
const handleOpenUserMenu = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => {
    setAnchorElUser(event.currentTarget);
};
```

Comment: If you're not using typescript you can remove the `: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>` part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's a *.jsx file, just remove : React.MouseEvent. It's a type for typescript.